# Can Sitecore's LDAP adapter be used on Sitecore 6.x?

Tags: sitecore

We've been looking into ways to get our client's Sitecore (6.4.1 rev. 110720) hooked up to their Active Directory setup. The first thing we came across was the [LDAP module](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/LDAP.aspx) for Sitecore. The client likes the "Live Validation Mode" of the LDAP connector, so we started looking into that. However, it became quickly clear that SDN shows that they haven't tested the LDAP module with Sitecore 6.x.

Then we found the [AD module](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/AD.aspx), which is clearly made for Sitecore 6.x. However, it seems to always operate in what the LDAP module documentation called "Mixed Mode" (that is, a robust 2-way sync of users and roles).

I have two questions. Does the LDAP module work on Sitecore 6.x? If not, is there a way to configure the AD module to only sync roles/groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LDAP module is the predecessor of the AD module and it doesn't work for Sitecore 6.x. Sitecore 6.x security is totally based on the ASP.NET security model, and this is what differs it from LDAP module completely.

The AD module is most likely able to satisfy your needs. If you only want the roles from AD in your Sitecore solution, then you should just plug in the role provider, and do not plug in the membership and profile providers. You might also want to enable RolesInRoles membership feature, because you'll most likely want to make your AD roles members of the standard Sitecore security roles. The RolesInRoles can do this for you.

It's all in the AD module documentation. If you're looking for the AD integration for your Sitecore solution, the AD module is the way to go.

Comment: I did read through the AD Module documentation and the membership features and the Roles-in-Roles concept. I guess I never connected the dots that I could just only use the roles provider. Thanks!

Comment: What I what do, if not already done, is define roles and permissions in Sitecore and then add AD roles to those, that way you are not dependent on Item<=>AD to define. Make the account you connect to AD with read-only/limited permissions so no need to worry about 2 way sync.